# Open RTSP link in Media Player on Android with Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, rtsp, live-streaming

Please I am trying to open an RTSP link from Phonegap on Android using

```
window.open('rtsp://brekete.myurl.org:1935/radio/liveradio', '_system')
```

but I am getting the error "Application Error : The protocol isn't supported.(rtsp://myurl.com)

How do I get phonegap to open this link with Android throwing this exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally resolved this issue by adding this tag to my config.xml

```
<access origin="*://myurl.org"/>
```

Comment: May i know how can we show a rtsp stream in mobile app using phonegap? You are opening stream using window.open()....but this is a javascript method to open any web page. Can you please provide a sample code...I will be highly thankful to you.